# Add/Remove Contacts (EditText) + Category (SpinnerBox) Dynamically as many as we want

Tags: java, android

Are there any tutorials which describes how to Add/Remove Phone Number (EditText) dynamically as many as we want which binds to Categories (SpinnerBox) like {home, work, mobile, office}. Below is an image

[image]

Comment: cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a ListView and a custom ListView layout. By clicking the add Button you simply add another item to the ListView.

For realizing this you need to create a layout which represents the layout of a row, a DataModel that represent the content of a row and a CustomAdapter that extends an ArrayAdapter and maps your DataModel on the row layout.

For more info about this topic you can read this tutorial: [Android ListView with custom Adapter](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)